# How to change HTML range slider value with button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider

I am using a HTML range slider to zoom in and zoom out an image. I also want to show two buttons with slider like + for zoom and − for zoom out. When a user clicks on either of these buttons, the slider should also be moved. But I am unable to do this. Here is my code.

```
<div id="slider">
    <input id="slide" type="range" min="330" max="1200" step="30" value="330" onchange="ImageViewer.sliderAction(this.value)" />
</div>
```

Here is my function:

```
var sliderAction = function (value) {
    $sliderChosen.html(value);
    $("#img").width(value);
    $("#img").height(value);
};
```

When I click the button, I tried this:

```
btnZoomIn.click(function() {
    $("#slide").value();  //Want to change value but value is undefined.
});
```

Is there any way to change slider value and move it as well on button click?

Comment: .val() value is null

Comment: how about `attr('value')`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

use `val()`

```
 btnZoomIn.click(function() {
               //if value < max
               $("#slide").val(parseInt($("#slide").val())+30);  
               $("#slide").trigger('change');
            });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9jfst447/

Comment: you are right but there is a little mistake. $("#slide").val() do not return integer value. It return with double quote  like "450" and after add 30, it makes 45030 and the slider goes to max value. I did this and it works fine now. parseInt($("#slide").val())+30. It works fine now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use callback function of `.val()` and then trigger onchange event:

```
var sliderelement = $( "#slide" );
btnZoomIn.click(function() {
 sliderelement.val(function( index, value ) {
     return parseInt(value,10) + 30;
 });
 sliderelement[0].onchange()
});
```

Comment: Same case like above. Value changed but slider moved to its max value

Comment: @Umer: can you reproduce problem in fiddle and share the link?

Comment: i got my answer as i commented on above @madalin answer.

Comment: @Umer: ahh. parsing issue. i thought .val returns value in int format for range.